# get office 365 mail in oldest first order using OutlookServiceClient

Tags: email, office365

ResponseModel responseModel = new ResponseModel();
    var contacts = new List();
    OutlookServicesClient client = new OutlookServicesClient(new Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/"),
                    async()   =>
                    {
                        return oValidationResponse.access_token;
                    });
    try
      {
           var userDetail = await client.Me.Contacts.ExecuteAsync();

How I use it for `OrderBy` `CreatedDateTime` i.e

```
 var userDetail = await client.Me.Contacts.OrderBy(x=>x.CreatedDateTime).ExecuteAsync();
```

this syntax gives error `IContact not contain CreatedDateTime`, so now I have no other way to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you were retrieve the **contacts**. Here is an sample that retrieve the messages and order them with **ReceivedDateTime**.

```
 OutlookServicesClient client = new OutlookServicesClient(new Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/"), () =>
        {
            return Task.Delay(10).ContinueWith(t => accessToken);
        });

        var Messages = client.Me.Messages.OrderBy(msg => msg.ReceivedDateTime).Take(20).ExecuteAsync().Result;
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var msg in Messages.CurrentPage)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"({++i,-3}:){msg.Subject,-50}:\t{msg.ReceivedDateTime,-30}");
        }
```

More detail about the mail rest refer to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations).